# Matlab code for generating rank deficient random matrix of order $m\times n$

Tags: matlab

I am trying to make matlab code for generating rank deficient random matrix of order $m\times n$, $m > n$.

**Rank deficient matrix**: Here $m\times n$, $m > n$ matrix $A$ would be rank deficient if $rank (A) = r < n$. I think this could be done by putting $n+1$ columns equal to zero. But I am just beginner to Matlab that is why getting little difficulty implement this.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you could tell us what a rank deficient random matrix is?

Comment: @Paul I will edit my question. Thanks

Comment: Is your issue with the mathematics or with programming? If you're trying to do this in Matlab, show us what you'e tried so far. Questions mainly about programming are off-topic here – StackOverflow is a better venue.

Comment: @horchler I didn't think my question is off topic. Any ways thanks for your time.